# Canvas Install error on windows cannot open include file Cairo.h

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, npm, node-gyp

I had tried to install canvas with command npm install -g canvas.
I get the following error.

```
   c:\...\node_modules\canvas\src\Canvas.h(19): fatal error C1083: Cannot 
   open include file: 'cairo.h': No such file or directory (compiling source 
   file ..\src\CanvasGradient.cc)  
   [C:\...\pdf-ptimise\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]
```

I had followed the steps mentioned in the following url still i get this error.

```
  https://github.com/benjamind/delarre.docpad/blob/master/src/documents/posts/installing-node-canvas-for-windows.html.md
```

please help me in resolving this issue.

With Many Thanks,
Bharath AK

Comment: Hi All, I had stopped continuing on windows.  Thanks for letting me know.  With Thanks and regards, Bharath AK